# cmd dir write file size in windows 10 in Gb instead of byte

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, directory, size

I use command

```
dir L01\*.gz /o-s/-c > L01.txt
```

to find all gz files in directory and sort by size. It works well! 
But, I need to take size in Gb not in bytes!

> ```
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        3018394731 v3000418221_L01_82_1.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2883376937 v3000418221_L01_82_2.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2875257587 v3000418221_L01_69_1.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2785098410 v3000418221_L01_69_2.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2520038171 v3000418221_L01_99_1.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2478618550 v3000418221_L01_62_1.fq.gz
> 01/24/2020  12:36 AM        2470651439 v3000418221_L01_99_2.fq.gz
> ```

also I need only filenames and sizes in Gb without date and time

And, it will be great if command do it with files in all subdirectures and give output like:

> ```
> directory L01 (or smth else):
> v3000418221_L01_82_1.fq.gz 2.5 Gb
> v3000418221_L01_82_2.fq.gz 2.4 Gb
>
> directory L02 : 
> v3000418221_L01_12_1.fq.gz 2.1 Gb
> v3000418221_L01_32_2.fq.gz 0.4 Gb 
> v3000418221_L01_42_1.fq.gz 1.5 Gb
> v3000418221_L01_8_2.fq.gz 2.4 Gb
> ```

It is not my computer so I try to do it in cmd without installing python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following in PowerShell to search the current directory, which will output `FileInfo` objects sorted by `Length` (Size) and with size converted to GB.

**Output to Console Only**

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*L01*.gz' | Sort Length -Desc |
    Select LastWriteTime,Name,@{n='SizeGB';e={$_.Length/1GB}}
```

If you want set the directory within the command, you can add `-Path DirectoryPath` to your `Get-ChildItem` command. The `-Recurse` switch allows for a recursive directory search from the search directory. See [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7).

If you want the pipe the output to a file as is, you can just add `| Out-File L01.txt` or `| Set-Content L01.txt`.

In PowerShell, `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. So you can use `dir -Filter '*L01*.gz'` if you feel the need.

**Output to File Without Table Headers**

PowerShell works with objects. If your objects have property names, they will by default appear as column headers in a table output. If you want the headers removed, you can just pipe your output to `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*L01*.gz' | Sort Length -Desc |
    Select LastWriteTime,Name,@{n='SizeGB';e={$_.Length/1GB}} |
        Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Set-Content L01.txt
```

**Output to File From CMD Shell**

If you only want to run code from the cmd shell, then you can still execute the PowerShell code there. Just put the PowerShell code in a script file `Something.ps1`.

```
Powershell.exe -File Something.ps1
```

---

There are some differences in default encoding for [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7) and [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7). In Windows PowerShell `>` redirects output (can target a file or stream) and uses Unicode with BOM. `Out-File` behaves the same as the redirect operator when no parameters are supplied. In PowerShell Core or just PowerShell (as of v7), both commands should output to files by default in UTF-8 with no BOM. `Set-Content` outputs using the culture-specific `Default` encoding. Both commands have an `-Encoding` parameter for you to control your output encoding.